# Using default debug key by sdk for google maps

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

For past few weeks i am trying to run basic google map application but all i get is grey grids when i run on emulator and even on android device!. I registered for Google map API key by **using the default debug key generated by SDK** is this causing the problem? and also i want to know more about how to get my own private key in eclipse JUNO .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google maps will not work on emulator if emulator doesn't have google play installed same is the case with android device. How are you testing on android device ?

Comment: @VaibhavAjayGupta i don't know about android device but i have installed google play but i am getting only grey grids when i run the Applications